# matplotlib is showing same time

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot time (seconds) on X-axis but it is showing error.

```
     import sys,os,time,numpy,pytz,numpy as np
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     import matplotlib.dates as md
     from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MinuteLocator

     class TUGData:
       def plot_data(self): # To generate Graph
           self.flttime1=[0.568,-0.2535,-0.01145,0.99573,-0.09156, 0.01344,-0.01710,0.00244]
           self.fLaZ1=[0.03256,0.99853,-0.0435841,0.03299,0.00977,-0.00733,0.01099,0.99988]

           plt.plot(self.flttime1,self.fLaZ1,'b-',label='Z axis (Left Data)')

           plt.grid()
```

Till above I can produce graph with out errors but when I am trying to plot time on x-axis, I got errors.

```
    ##        rm.xaxis_date()
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate = md.DateFormatter('%M:%S')
    loc=md.AutoDateLocator(tz=None, minticks=5, maxticks=10)
    hfmt = md.AutoDateFormatter(loc)
    hfmt.scaled[1./24.] = '%M:%S'
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(md.AutoDateLocator(loc))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.AutoDateFormatter(hfmt))
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()


   s=TUGData() 
   s.plot_data()
```

My basic aim is to have seconds on x-axis starting with 0 and higher limit should be auto selected. How to achieve that? Pls guide me.

Comment: Can you modify your exampl so it is copy-paste runable?  Without your data, that this seems to be a class method pulled out of context, and you are using some import aliases with out telling us what they are this is very hard to debug.

Comment: Hello, Can I get your mail Id to contact you?

Comment: Please keep all mpl related correspondence in a public channel (SO, mpl mailing lists or github issues).

Comment: Now you have swung too far the other way and have posted way too much irrelevant code.  Almost no one is going to wade through that much code to sort out what is wrong.  You should be able to replicated your mpl issue in < 20 lines of code (including synthetic data).

Comment: I believe, this should be fine now... @tcaswell

Comment: @tcaswell can you help me with this?